# Multithreaded MongoDB C++ client application: multiple DBClientConnections vs. a single mutex-locked one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb

Which should be faster, theoretically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither, use a ScopedDbConnection. It will take care making a connection pool and make sure that threads don't step on each other, as long as you don't share a single ScopedDbConnection between threads.